# running commands in WSL2 / Ubuntu 20.04 from PowerShell?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, ubuntu-20.04, wsl2

I want to run some commands (some of which require sudo) on my Ubuntu 20.04 / WSL2 instance via PowerShell.

Any ideas as to if this is possible?

For the time being I just want to know if I can run a command like `echo test >> output.txt`.

Longer term I'd like to be able to get the IP address of the WSL2 / Ubuntu 20.04 VM by doing `ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet ' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $2}'` or some such and then using that IP address to update my Windows 10 hosts file and using that IP address in `sed` to replace the IP addresses in some local config files but...  baby steps lol.

First things first, I just want to see if I can run commands!

Comment: Which commands exactly?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the article
[Run Linux tools from a Windows command line](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop).

The syntax is:

```
wsl linux-command
```