# Running multiple commands in WSL2 / Ubuntu 22.04 from PowerShell

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, automation, wsl2

I have to run a chain of commands in wsl from powershell, I've stumbled upon this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1618189/running-commands-in-wsl2-ubuntu-20-04-from-powershell) while researching, but I cant use `&&` with `wsl` (`wsl "ls && ls"` returns with `bash: line 1: ls && ls: command not found`, while `wsl ls && ls` runs `ls` from `wsl` and then from `powershell`). How do I make it run a chain of commands?

In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems), mentioned on the only answer, it is also stated that commands are run from current directory, but for me `wsl ls` returns with results from `/`, regardless of current directory in powershell. But this is secondary, since I could overcome it with a `cd` to current directory if I could chain a number of commands to run in `wsl`.

I could also chain wsl commands, instead of commands in wsl (like `wsl ls && wsl ls`), but I couldn't change the working directory, so it isn't an option without the second issue being resolved.

I've managed to somewhat achieve my goals with the following functions in my powershell profile file, but if there are any better options, I'd love to hear them.

```
function getWSLPath {
    param (
        [string]$Path = (Get-Location).Path
    )

    # Replace backslashes with forward slashes
    $wslPath = $Path.Replace('\', '/')

    # Replace 'C:' with '/mnt/c', 'D:' with '/mnt/d', etc.
    $driveRegex = '^[A-Za-z]:'
    if ($wslPath -match $driveRegex) {
        $driveLetter = $wslPath.Substring(0, 1).ToLower()
        $wslPath = $wslPath -replace $driveRegex, "/mnt/$driveLetter"
    }

    return $wslPath
}

function wslHere([string] $command) {
    $path = getWSLPath
    wsl "$command" "$path"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to escape the ampersands for this command to work.
The escape character to use depends on the context.

**Command Prompt (cmd)**

```
wsl ls ^&^& ls
```

**PowerShell**

```
wsl ls `&`& ls
```

Comment: Thats the right answer, thank you. Do you know why my wsl commands would default to root folder, though when I just use `wsl` - it opens with current directory. Also I wasn't able to run anything but basic linux commands (for example npm doesn't work) using wsl <command>, perhaps you know how I could fix it?

Comment: A WSL2 distribution is running in its own virtual machine, so the interface with your computer is somewhat clunky.